# Create rewrite rule, if contains a uri segmet redirect to php else go to a html file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

Right now I'm using artisan as my webserver since I'm working locally and on server.php it's possible to emulate mod_rewrite:

```
// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' and file_exists($requested))
{
    return false;
}
if(substr( $uri, 0, 5 ) === '/api/')
    require_once $paths['public'].'/index.php';
else
    require_once $paths['public'].'/index.html';
```

So what I'm doing is, if my route is something like this:

> www.mydomain.com/api/something

The `index.php` will be responsible for that request

For everything else it will be `index.html`

Both files are inside the public folder.

Since soon I will deploy this to my webserver, how could I accomplish the same thing with a `.htacces`?

This what I have, but I don't think this will work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    <Location /api>
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Location>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: If I was you I _would_ install a real web server (and configure it as closely as possible to the production server) – that way, you will have the least number of possible surprises in the end. And you could already know if rewriting the way you want it to do would work or not. The _“convenient way”_ you are promised in the comment just results in _more_ work in the end IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# handle /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (^|/)api(/|$) index.php [L,NC]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```